# RoR - Adding form over a static page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, static-pages

Can someone tell me how do I add a simple form in my rails app? I created a form on a separate page and it works fine, but how do I implement it on my static page?

My app/views/contact/_form.html.haml

```
.container
  %h1 Contact
  = simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
    = f.input :name, :required => true
    = f.input :email, :required => true
    = f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => false, :input_html => {:rows => 10}

    .hidden
      = f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!'
    .form-actions
      = f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary"
```

My contacts controller:

```
    class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
        @contact.request = request
        if @contact.deliver
            flash.now[:error] = nil
        else
            flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
            render :new
        end
    end

end
```

Where I want to add the form, (index.html.haml)(static page)

```
#callouts2
.callout_inner
    .wrapper
        .callout
            =render 'contacts/form'
```

My routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :posts do
    member do
      get "like", to: "posts#upvote"
      get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
    end
    resources :comments
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root 'posts#index', as: "authenticated_root"
  end

  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]

  root 'pages#index'
```

I also have another 'Thank you for your message' page in views/contact/create.html.haml, I need to redirect them to that page as well.

EDIT: I added a `=render 'contacts/form'` inside my index page but it gives me an error:

> ArgumentError in Pages#index Showing
>   C:/Sites/blogger/app/views/contacts/_form.html.haml where line #3 raised:
>
> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Trace of
>   template inclusion: app/views/pages/index.html.haml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is called "_form", You could do something like:

```
render "form"
```

I'm not familiar with haml, not sure what other syntax is required, but that is how you add a form into a page.

Comment: The syntax for haml is `= render 'form'` I added it to my index page, but it gave me an ArgumentError, that "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Comment: Fixed it! I added `= simple_form_for(Contact.new) do |f|` in my form and it worked, although I know this is not a good practice. But do you have another alternative?

Comment: Not sure why this is a bad practice? Do you mean in haml? The haml kind of gets in the way for me as I only really know ERB. Every form needs to know what it is being used for, that's why you got the error at first. If you mean the 'Contact.new' then just change it to your instance variable. i.e. `= simple_form_for(@contact)...`